# Explanation of reputation system in meta.math

Tags: discussion, meta-reputation

I currently have 405 reputation on meta.math. Since I have *literally* **never** posted any answer or question here, this would be my first, I would assume that this reputation gets *generated* somehow from my rep on the main site. But I have, as of now, 434 rep there. How exactly does this work then. Maybe there is an explanation somewhere on the FAQ itself, but I couldn't find it.

I am not complaining about getting 405 rep *for free* though, just curious. :)

Comment: I think the your math.SE rep gets transfered to the meta rep once every hour. So in a few minutes you will be 29 points richer!

Comment: It's already there :-)

Comment: Oh yes, I see. Got it :)

Comment: You might also have a look at older posts tagged ([meta-tag:meta-reputation]) or [(meta)+(reputation)](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meta+reputation) for more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [help center](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta):

> Votes on meta do not affect your reputation; your meta reputation is the same as your reputation on Mathematics Stack Exchange (synchronized hourly), though you earn separate badges. You must have 5 reputation to participate on meta.

See also: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10765/does-voteup-down-in-msemeta-affect-reputation-in-mse-or-the-converse, http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6721/how-long-is-the-time-of-the-transfer-of-the-reputation-value-from-the-main-to-th and the meta.SO post [Do I get any reputation from being upvoted/accepted on per-site-metas?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96322/do-i-get-any-reputation-from-being-upvoted-accepted-on-per-site-metas/)

---

However, although they are not shown in the form of reputation, the numbers of upvotes/downvotes or meta are still registered by the system. So it is possible to obtain "reputation-based" badges such as [mortarboard](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/41/mortarboard), [reversal](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/57/reversal), [populist](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/39/populist)  or [tag badges](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/help/badges?tab=tags) on meta. (Maybe it would be more precise to call them "score-based badges" or "upvotes-based badges"?)